# label printer incorrectly prints itextsharp documents

Tags: c#, itext

the code below generate pdf documents:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("st.csv", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (StreamReader configFile = new StreamReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250")))
                    {
                        string line = string.Empty;

                        while ((line = configFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                            {
                                line = line.Replace("\"", "");
                                string[] varible = line.Split(';');
                                string number = varible[0];
                                string stName = varible[1];
                                string ewidenceNumber = varible[2];
                                string fileName = "barcodes\\" + Encryption.RandomString(10, true) + ".png";

                                Generate(line, fileName);

                                PdfPTable Table = new PdfPTable(2);
                                Table.WidthPercentage = 100;
                                Table.SetWidths(new[] { 110f, 190f });
                                iTextSharp.text.Image barcode = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(fileName);
                                barcode.Border = 0;
                                barcode.ScalePercent(180f);
                                PdfPCell imageCell = new PdfPCell(barcode);
                                imageCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                                Table.AddCell(imageCell);
                                PdfPCell descriptionCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(
                                    "Enterprise 1 \n\n" +
                                    number + "\n\n" +
                                    "Number1:  " + stName + "\n\n" +
                                    "Number2:  " + ewidenceNumber, _standardFont));
                                descriptionCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                                descriptionCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                                Table.AddCell(descriptionCell);
                                Table.KeepTogether = true;
                                Table.SpacingAfter = 10f;
                                doc.Add(Table);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and here is the problem: vertical and horizontal view in adobe acrobat displays correctly, but when I need to print labels with this information CITIZEN label printer always prints it in horizontal view. I can't adapt this data to print in correct orientation. Anyone has solution for this problem? Maybe I incorrectly rotate cells in table?

Comment: When you create doc, you pass a PageSize parameter. Does it include rotation? Some programs might ignore that rotation setting and, thus, align the document in an unwanted way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you drop PDF and instead write to it's native format: http://www.citizen-europe.com/support/progman.htm

PDF printing support is supplied by the driver.  If the driver doesn't know how to interpret the specific PDF commands then it's not going to work.  Usually label printers don't provide very good driver support for anything but writing to their native format or emulating ZPL (zebra) and Datamax.